# What is the meaning of different mysql timeouts

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, timeout, database-connection

I searched a lot on the internet but not found any brief explanation on mysql timeouts with examples. I want to know the meaning of mysql diffenernt timeouts as listed below and also want to know why and when we use them.

```
+----------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name              | Value    |
+----------------------------+----------+
| connect_timeout            | 10       |
| delayed_insert_timeout     | 300      |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout   | 50       |
| interactive_timeout        | 28800    |
| net_read_timeout           | 3        |
| net_write_timeout          | 60       |
| slave_net_timeout          | 3600     |
| wait_timeout               | 28800    |
+----------------------------+----------+
```

Also in ruby on rails application i can set `read_timeout` in my database.yml file. if query is not able to read the data within specified `read_timeout` value mysql will close the connection. so i also want to know what is the differentce between `net_read_timeout` and `read_timeout`

Thanks,

Comment: Did you find any answer regarding this ?

Answer (score 0):

From [The Ultimate Guide to Ruby Timeouts](https://github.com/ankane/the-ultimate-guide-to-ruby-timeouts/blob/master/README.md)

> connect (or open) - time to open the connection
>
> read (or receive) - time to receive data after connected
>
> write (or send) - time to send data after connected
>
> checkout - time to checkout a connection from the pool
>
> statement - time to execute a database statement